# Android Dialog show HTML in TextView from String

Tags: android, html, dialog, textview

I'm trying to show HTML code in a dialog but the HTML needs to be stored in a string which is first put into a textview.

I have found many other questions about something similar but most are setting the text in code rather than in strings.xml. None I found seem to use a 'dialog to textview to string with html' process.
I've done so far what I think should work but I'm getting an error now (below). I've tried other ways but cannot get the HTML effects to show.

I'm still new to Android so any help to see what I'm doing wrong would be great. Thanks.

preferencesActivity.java - OnCreate

```
       Preference myPref = (Preference) findPreference("pref_showHelp");
       myPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

                        Dialog dialog = new  dialog(preferencesActivity.this);
                        helpFile_textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helpFile_textView);
                        helpFile_textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.helpFile_text))); // Line 44
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.helpfile);
                        dialog.setTitle("Help");
                        dialog.show();

                      return false;
                    }
                });
}
```

helpfile .xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/helpFile_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/helpFile_text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Strings .xml

```
<string name="helpFile_text">Test of <b>bold and <u>underline</u> and bullet &#8226;</string>
```

Logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1516): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(1516):     at com.example.newcalc.preferencesActivity$1.onPreferenceClick(preferencesActivity.java:44)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
helpFile_textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helpFile_textView);
helpFile_textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.helpFile_text)));
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.helpfile);
```

to

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.helpfile);     
helpFile_textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.helpFile_textView);
helpFile_textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.helpFile_text)));
```

You have to inflate the layout that you want to use in the `Dialog` before you can find it using `findViewById`

Also since the `id` you want to find (i.e. `helpFile_textView`) is in the layout that you inflated in `dialog` you have to use `dialog.findViewById` instead of `findViewById` to get the `TextView`

Also

```
Dialog dialog = new dialog(preferencesActivity.this);
```

should be

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(preferencesActivity.this);
```

but i think that is a typo.

Comment: Thanks @Apoorv that fixed the error and made perfect sense once you explained it. Thanks! (And yes that was just a typo on SO).
One mention though is that the HTML still didn't format - but something I saw in other answers is that the string needs to be put inside '<![CDATA[<b>bold</b> and <u>underline</u>]]'

Comment: Sorry i have no idea about that but i generally use the `<html>` and `<body>` tags and then everything in between them. That works for me you can give it a try.

Comment: @Apoorv hey +1 up from me>

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.helpfile);    
helpFile_textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.helpFile_textView);    
helpFile_textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(preferencesActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.helpFile_text)));
```

for more correction refer @Aproov's answer.

Comment: Thanks for this, this was correct too but marked Aproov's answer as it had more explanation.

Comment: @SteddyRyan it's ok. and off course Apoorv's answer is _best_.